# git: I can add a directory, but at commit time I get "nothing to commit"

Tags: git, github, commit, github-for-mac

I'm trying to add two directories to a git repo. 
I can add them OK, but when trying to "commit", I get "nothing to commit".
I'm following the add->commit->push sequence, but in this case it doesn't seem to be working. 
I have already pulled everything from the repo.

Any hints?
thanks![image]

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore ?  Have you checked that the folder isn't being ignored?  `git status --ignored`

Comment: No the problem was not with .gitignore. I touched/added/committed/pushed again and it worked. I'm sure I was missing something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will be able to commit as soon as you make a change to/add a file. Adding a directory to git can't be commited itself; you need to add/edit a file inside the directory.

Try adding something in css and comitting afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Git only tracks *files* - when you run `git add <directory>`, what you're actually doing is telling Git to add the contents of any files in that directory. Since the directory is currently empty, it doesn't add anything, and thus there's nothing to commit.

For instance, the following would work:

```
$ touch css/main.css
$ git add css
$ git commit -m "Add empty main CSS file"
```

Answer (score 2):

As everybody says, git track only files, not directories. So you can't add empty directory into it. You can make a trick by adding empty `.gitignore` in directory `css` and commit it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are only two posibilities.

1. You are in the wrong directory.
2. You have a gitignore with blocks the folders / files to add.

You can check it when you modify a file in your css directory and look with

`#git status`

wheather the file is modified.

When there are no changes then check your `.gitignore`files.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason I had a directory baseservices.demo/ that would not get committed. I changed the name to baseservices/ and no problem. Maybe an issue with the (.), or maybe the way I was adding the files? I'm not really sure but changing (mv) the name worked for me.